# Pass message to Chrome extension content script without specifying it as a background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a feature to the Chrome context menu to add a todo item from selected text. I pass the selected text from a context menu in `background.js` like so:

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  chrome.extension.sendMessage(info.selectionText, function(){});
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

  chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Add: %s", "contexts":["selection"]});

});
```

And then listen for the message in an `app.js` content script:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(task, sender, sendResponse) {
  Task.setNewTask(task); // Saves the task in storage
});
```

The message is received correctly when my extension is open in a tab, but doesn't work when it is closed. This is because I don't set `app.js` as a background script in my `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "notifications"
],

"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

The reason I don't include `app.js` as a background script is because it includes the rest of my app's code, which generates errors when tried to run in the background without a DOM.

Unfortunately I can't easily do the storage in the `background.js` file because I need access to the function `Task.setNewTask` which is in my content script.

My app has various methods of storing data depending on the environment – there would be a lot of duplication if I had to put this logic in `background.js`.

I've tried including my app as a background page:

```
"background": {
  "page": "index.html"
},
```

And then including both scripts at the bottom of the page:

```
  <script src="background.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

But my app still won't add new tasks in the background.

Is there a way to:

- Keep `background.js` as simple as possible,
- Not include `app.js` as a background script,
- Still receive a message when `app.js` is not in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear. Where did you find the base code you're modifying?

`chrome.extension.sendMessage`/`chrome.extension.onMessage` **are deprecated** to the point of not even being in the documentation anymore.

But even if you change them to the proper `chrome.runtime` equivalents, it's still the wrong function to communicate with a content script.

1. Your original code fails, since `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` (and **deprecated** `chrome.extension` equivalent) are sending only to extension pages (e.g. to the `chrome-extension://yourid/` origin), not to content scripts.
2. Your modified code fails, since messaging never sends a message to the same JS context it's running from.

What you need is `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` function, that allows you to specify the tab where your context script is. If you want to send it to the current tab, it's passed as a parameter to the `onClicked` listener.

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, info.selectionText);
}
```

On the context script side, don't forget to change to `chrome.runtime`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(task, sender, sendResponse) {
  Task.setNewTask(task); // Saves the task in storage
});
```